# .htaccess redirect refers to folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these htaccess-rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.de\/subpage$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/subpage.html/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/subpage.htm/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't get it. Usually htaccess-redirects are no problem, but this here drives me crazy.

When I open `mydomain.de/subpage` it tries to open the folder (or throws an 404 for not existing resource). Instead I want my htaccess-rule to trigger. What am I missing?

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} represents your domain name, so /subpage is not part of match in %{HTTP_HOST} variable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got it. **Starkeen** gave me a direction. Had to use variatons of condition-types: this is my working result:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.de(/)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subpage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.de/new_page_html [R=301,L]
```